# removeEventListener in setInterval

Tags: javascript

I need to add new EventListener with help setInterval, but i can't remove old EventListener.
`getEventListeners(document)` to see, that document to add "mouseup", every 100ms
I not finded similar question

```js
let tt = function() { 
   let qq = function() {  console.log(1)}
   document.removeEventListener('mouseup', qq, true); 
   document.addEventListener('mouseup', qq, true);
 }
 setInterval( tt, 100)
```

Comment: Just move `let qq = ...` out of the function. Btw doesn't look like a bright solution anyway

Comment: `qq` is local to `tt`, it's recreated every time the function is executed. But, most likely there's another way, you really should not add and remove event listeners in an interval.

Comment: You're trying to remove the *new* event listener before you've added it (and ignoring the old one entirely).

Comment: @Teemu
 setInterval is "the crutch" for my code, to catch other event=) 
"Just move let qq = ... out of the function." - yes it is creating only one event mouseup, even to commented "removeEventListener"

Comment: If you've a boss, I'm pretty sure he/she is not going to like your interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefine the qq function every time tt called, so it is a new object, and can not be matched on event listener removal process:
[matching event listeners for removal.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#matching_event_listeners_for_removal)

If we define function once with var, it works:

```
var qq = function() {  console.log(1)}

let tt = function() { 

  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', qq, true); 
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', qq, true);
}
setInterval( tt, 100)
```

Comment: it`s helped me. but i think that removeEventListener is not necessary. It is like for events "on" and if event is absolute identically that "removeListener" not necessary. Or am i wrong? thanks everyone!

Comment: A nice inference. You are right.